# I get an error with snapshot.data()["~~~"] flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the value from Firestore with the following code. But I'm sorry I got this error. Help me

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user.uid).get();

print(snapshot.data()["location"] as String);
```

Details of the error

```
The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

[image]

I tried various things, for example `print(snapshot.data()!['location'] as String);`
[image]

error code

````
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.  Try defining the operator '[]'.```
````

Comment: can you please give your feedback on the answers posted below?

Comment: Like the comment I tried, but I got an error.
So I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

As you might be able to guess, you are getting an error because if the snapshot has no data, it will return `null`, which will error. Here are some ways of fixing it:

1. adding a bang operator (`!`) (But you say this did not fix the issue?)

```
print(snapshot.data()!['location'] as String);
```

note the `!` after `data()`, the bang operator tells dart to ignore a nullable value, this code will work as long as `snapshot.data()` is not null, of course, this is not safe, because `snapshot.data()` *could* be null, so here is an obvious solution:

```
var data = snapshot.data();
if (data != null) {
  print(data!['location'] as String);
}
```

this should work, because now if data is null, the print statement will simply not run.

2. adding a `?` operator

```
print(snapshot?['location']);
```

note the `?` after `data()`, the `?` operator will escalate a null value, so if `snapshot.data()` is **not null**, `snapshot.data()?['location']` will be equal to `snapshot.data()['location']`, but if `snapshot.data()` **is null**, `snapshot.data()?['location']` will be equal to `null` instead of throwing an error.

3. Adding a `??` operator

```
print(snapshot.data()?['location'] ?? 'the value was null');
```

Here, it is necessary to use both the `?` operator to escalate the null value and the `??` operator.

The `??` operator will output the value on the left if the value is not null and will output the value on the right if the value on the left is null, so in this case, if `snapshot.data()` is null, that will escalate the null value, meaning `snapshot.data()?['location']` will be null, which in turn means that instead of printing `'null'`, the `??` operator will print `'the value was null'`

So to conclude, if you are sure the value is not null, you can use the bang operator `!`, if you are not sure, then you can use a combination of `?` and `??` to your advantage.

### Edit

It looks like adding one of the above solutions still won't fix the issue, here is an updated version that will hopefully fix the new issues?

```
print((snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>)['location'] as String);
```

Comment: Thx. Like the comment I tried, but I got an error. So I edited the question

Comment: I edited my asnwer with a new line of code, could you try it to see if it fiexes the new issue?

Comment: OMG I can solve this solution with your answer

Comment: Very happy it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

you need to add null check operator to make sure that receiver is not null.

```
print(snapshot.data()!["location"] as String);
```

Comment: Thx. Like the comment I tried, but I got an error. So I edited the question